# How to find out why a PC motherboard is dead

Tags: motherboard

I am trying to find out what is causing a problem with my desktop motherboard which won't power on or even receive a power to light up all LEDs once the PSU is switched ON.

Does this strange CPU scratches means a defective CPU which not allowing me to power on a motherboard?

I should note that thermal paste was removed so its clean.

[image]

I tried to jump start a PSU while it was disconnected to test it, and while it was plugged into motherboard in 24 pins. But it did not helped to boot, only power on which was different from the normal Powering On.

Do not understand actually how to check if the CAPACITORS are fine or not as they are a little bit different from my previous boards.

Here are some pics:

### 1

[image: VIDEO MOTHERBOARD PROBLEM]

### 2

[image]

### 3

[image]

### 4

[image]

### 5

[image]

### 6

[image]

Can someone tell me if there are any visible damages on the board , pls ?

### Video of jump-starting the board while it's plugged into the PSU

[VIDEO MOTHERBOARD PROBLEM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vaXg3MiKKQ)

Comment: Is it making any beeping sound on power on?

Comment: I would take out the memory and see if it makes any noise. Does not sound promising.

Comment: Do you have a known good power supply to try?

Comment: Might want to return the PS and get yourself a new mobo! :)

Comment: @EddieDunn - Buying a new mobo will force me to buy a corresponding CPU for it, as mine will be no more compatible with a new sockets, so wasting approx. 800$ is a way to hard for me now :(

Comment: To upgrade, yes. I bet you can find a decent price for one that has the socket you need, way less than $200 I would think.

Comment: @EddieDunn - maybe I'm missing something, but I really can't find anything like that. No stores here in Paris have a LGA 2011 Socket X79 (sandy bridge) motherboard version. If you know, I will be glad to link me

Comment: I see stuff for $400-ish. http://www.amazon.com/ASUS-P9X79-WS-Intel-Motherboard/dp/B00686I638/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1449857784&sr=8-8&keywords=lga+2011+x79